# php late static binding revieve error expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I am new to OOP and I have been working on this example but I cannot seem to get rid of this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\...\php_late_static_bindings.php on line 16`

I was attempting to execute the follow code:

```
abstract class father {
    protected $lastname="";
    protected $gender="";

    function __construct($sLastName){
        $this->lastname = $sLastName;
    }

    abstract function getFullName();

    public static function create($sFirstName,$sLastName){
        return new self($sFirstName,$sLastName);
    };
}

class boy extends father{
    protected $firstname="";

    function __construct($sFirstName,$sLastName){
        parent::__construct($sLastName);
        $this->firstname = $sFirstName;
    }

    function getFullName(){
        return("Mr. ".$this->firstname." ".$this->lastname."<br />");
    }
}

class girl extends father{
    protected $firstname="";

    function __construct($sFirstName,$sLastName){
        parent::__construct($sLastName);
        $this->firstname = $sFirstName;
    }

    function getFullName(){
        return("Ms. ".$this->firstname." ".$this->lastname."<br />");
    }

}


$oBoy = boy::create("John", "Doe");
print($oBoy->getFullName());
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
    $oGirl = girl::create("Jane", "Doe");
    print($oGirl->getFullName());

Comment: `return new static` should be the call.  Because otherwise it'll try to instantiate the abstract class (which will fail)...  But what's line 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to **remove the semi-colon that's after your method definition** :

```
public static function create($sFirstName,$sLastName){
    return new self($sFirstName,$sLastName);
} // there was a semi-colon, here
```

Then, **you probably want to use `static`, and not `self`**, here :

```
public static function create($sFirstName,$sLastName){
    return new static($sFirstName,$sLastName);
}
```

Explanation :

- `self` points to the class in which it is written -- here, the `father` class, which is abstract, and cannot be instanciated.
- `static`, on the other hand, means *late static binding* -- and, here, will point to your `boy` class ; which is the one you want to instanciate.

Comment: +1 But remember that late static binding will work only as of PHP 5.3 :)

Comment: I removed the semi-colon and changed self to static I now receive the error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\brjulias_dev\php_late_static_bindings.php on line 14

Comment: Heu... are you sure you are using PHP >= 5.3 ? Late Static Binding didn't exist with PHP < 5.3

Comment: Yes it does :-) *(don't forget to read http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php )*

Answer (score 0):

PHP's error reporting is usually pretty good. Just read the error. The problem is here:

```
public static function create($sFirstName,$sLastName){
    return new self($sFirstName,$sLastName);
};
```

Remove the training semicolon.

```
public static function create($sFirstName,$sLastName){
    return new self($sFirstName,$sLastName);
}
```

Comment: Alright that solved that issue I cannot believe I missed that